# Django model object changed after update

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a simple model as follows:

```
class Invite(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField()
    ....
    ....
```

In my view, I update an Invite entity:

```
invite_obj = Invite.objects.get(pk=id) # currently invite.status = "OLD"

print(invite_obj.status) # prints OLD

invite_serializer = CustomSerializer(invite_obj) # a custom serializer which updates the instance status from "OLD" to "NEW"

if invite_serializer.is_valid():
    invite_serializer.save()

print("after update", invite_obj.status) # prints NEW
```

variable invite_obj got modified after update. How did the variable storing the original entity is modified?

EDIT: code for custom serializer

```
class CustomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        with transaction.atomic():
           instance.status = "NEW"
           ...
           instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: How does the `CustomSerializer` looks like?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added code for CustomSerializer in the post

Comment: `instance.status = "NEW"` will set the status to `new` in case of an update. Since you pass an object to the `CustomSerializer`, it will thus update the `status`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you! I did not notice the same object was getting modified. deep copying solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

please change your this following code:

```
invite_obj = Invite.objects.get(pk=id) # currently invite.status = "OLD"

print(invite_obj.status) # prints OLD

invite_serializer = CustomSerializer(invite_obj) # a custom serializer which updates the instance status from "OLD" to "NEW"

if invite_serializer.is_valid():
    invite_serializer.save()

print("after update", invite_obj.status) # prints NEW
```

to:

```
invite_obj = Invite.objects.get(pk=id) # currently invite.status = "OLD"

print(invite_obj.status) # prints OLD

invite_serializer = CustomSerializer(instance = invite_obj, data=request.data) # a custom serializer which updates the instance status from "OLD" to "NEW"

if invite_serializer.is_valid():
    invite_serializer.save()

print("after update", invite_obj.status) # prints NEW
```

I hope it will work for yu for sure.

Comment: This did not work, I had to use deep copy